# How to create a cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am installing a software(web-base) and installation procedural is asking me to finally create a cron job to point to **public_html/cron.php**. This is the first time am hearing about cron job.

I want to know what exactly  cron job is and what the installation is asking me to do. I have inserted a link to the installation [PeerUp Documentation](https://www.docs.peerup.life/#installation)

Comment: yes...a command to an operating system or server for a job that is to be executed at a specified time.

Comment: but am confused!

Comment: What is the documentation wants me to do??

Comment: where actually do i run that??

Comment: is it in the address bar??

Answer (score 1):

Cron job is the way you can schedule your script to execute at specific time in repeated way.

For linux you can use command `crontab -e` to register your jobs with schedule.

Like if you have script that need to executed every minute.

```
1. Edit scheduler: $ crontab -e
2. Add line:  * * * * * php /home/public_html/cron.php
3. Save and exit
```

You can notice your script is running every minute. However if you need confirm yourself if its really executing then what you need is adding a log file which basically logs the script success or failure status every minute

Step #2 can be replaced with  "*  *  *  *  * php /home/public_html/cron.php > /home/public_html/cron.log 2>&1"

For more detail about cron job you can refer [here](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)